# Prompting personal warning before putting my Macbook Pro to sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I carry my Macbook Pro (15" Retina, Mid 2012 with Mt. Lion) between my work and home. It is connected to an external HDD as a Time Machine. I always forget to properly eject the HDD before putting my notebook to sleep (I rarely shut it down) at my office.

Is there a way to have it prompt with a custom reminder or warning when I try to put MBP to sleep, using Automator or something?

Comment: Do you put it to sleep by closing the lid? Using the keyboard shortcut? Selecting `Sleep` from the `` menu?

Comment: I do it by going to the Apple menu. Closing the lid would not give me any chance to see the warning.

Comment: Right. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an AppleScript to do this, then instead of picking sleep from the  menu, you can select your script from the Script menu.

All of this can be set up from within **AppleScript Editor**:

- Launch **AppleScript Editor**
- Open **Preferences**
- Check the box to "Show Script menu in menu bar". [image]
- Create a new script
- Here is the content of the script:

  ```
  display dialog "Are you sure you want to put the computer to sleep?"
  do shell script "pmset sleepnow"
  ```
- Save the script as `~/Library/Scripts/Applications/AppleScript Editor/Sleep.scpt`

Now you can put your computer to sleep from the script menu and be warned before sleeping.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I was looking for. Will try at the end of the day.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the drive automatically ejected when you sleep the mac instead?

Quick search found Jettison on the Mac App Store
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jettison/id447430809?mt=12

There is also an app you can use to run Apple script on sleep/wake:
http://www.lagentesoft.com/scenario/index.html